# Files added from "p4 add" not showing up in p4v default changelist

Tags: command-line, perforce

I have a P4CONFIG file that sets up necessary environment.
Then I `p4 add /path/to/myfile.ext`, which gives me

```
//Depot/relative/path/to/myfile.ext - currently opened for add
```

But when opening my p4v of the same workspace, the file isn't in the default changelist. I've also tried

```
p4 add -f /path/to/...
```

And the result is the same.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I missing?

There are a couple of possibilities.  The two commands to run to figure it out would be:

```
p4 info
p4 opened
```

The things you'd be trying to figure out with those commands are:

1. What workspace am I actually using at the command line?  Since you don't include this output in your question, it's possible that your P4CONFIG file isn't actually set up correctly (maybe it's getting overridden, maybe there's a typo in it, etc) and you have the file open in a different workspace from the one that you're using in P4V.
2. Which changelist is this file already open in?  You said that you're looking for the file in the default changelist, but it could be currently open in a different pending changelist in the same workspace.

Comment: Thanks. I found out that I was on a different workspace. Strange thing is that I also used a .p4config that points to that workspace, and p4 info confirms so, but it only worked after I restarted my PC. I also had to refresh P4V by hand to make it work.

Comment: I found that when using P4CONFIG, the command

    p4 set P4CONFIG=/path/to/.p4config.txt

writes the P4 environment variables into the registry, which in theory won't get updated until PC reboots. I suspect that this may be what I experienced.

Comment: `p4 set` takes effect immediately.  My guess is that you had previously set `P4CONFIG` via the native `set` command (incorrectly), which would override the value you set with `p4 set`, but would not persist after a reboot.  The way to validate this would be to run `p4 set` when the setting was incorrect; the output will tell you where it's reading each value from. If you set it in the environment via the native `set`, it'll show as `(environment)` rather than `(config)`.